# In WordPress, how can I replace the_title() with get_the_category_by_ID()?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a new developer and I just read in the WordPress Code Reference site that `the_title()` has been deprecated and `get_the_category_by_ID` should be used instead.
The thing is that I just can't find a way to replace it so that it successfully displays the title on each blog post. In the examples it seems to be used only for the categories.

Can anybody give me an example of how to do this properly, please?

Comment: Do you want replace the "post title" if it is on a specify category? Or Do you want replace all "post title"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the title using a wp hook. You can put this code, or inside the function.php on your theme; or in your plugin example:

```
function my_custom_replace_title( $title, $id = null ) {

    /* Put here your condition, you get the post ID on "$id", and the current title on "$title"*/    

    // by category
    //if ( in_category('XXX', $id ) ) {
    //    return '';
    //}
     //if ($title === 'custom text' ){
     //   return 'this is my new title';
    // }
    $title = 'My Custom Title - Forced'; // This is to test it.

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'my_custom_replace_title', 10, 2 );
```

I recommended to read https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title

I hope help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation Jose Carlos, That is exactly what I needed,